# SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Many-to-many model error in alias

Tags: sequelize.js

I've searched for some of the answers here at StackOverflow, but couldn't find any that solved my problem, so here it goes.
I have 2 models, Action and User. One user can like many actions, and one action can be liked by many users.

User.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const user = sequelize.define('User', {
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
        },
        username: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          unique: true
        },
      }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
      })

      user.associate = (models) => {
        user.hasMany(models.Action, {
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
        })

        user.belongsToMany(models.Action, {
          as: 'users_that_liked',
          through: 'Like',
          foreignKey: 'userId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
        })
      }

      return user
}
```

Action.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const action = sequelize.define('Action', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  })

  action.associate = (models) => {
    action.belongsTo(models.User, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    })

    action.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: 'Like',
      foreignKey: 'actionId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    })
  }

  return action
}
```

Here is my method:

```
get_action (req, res) {
    return Action
      .findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'title'],
        where: {
          id: req.params.id
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            attributes: ['id', 'name']
          }
          {
            model: User,
            as: 'users_that_liked'
          }
        ]
      })
      .then(action => res.status(200).send(action))
      .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error.toString()))
  }
```

With the first include I want to get the user that "posted" this action, and with the second I want to get all the users that liked this action.
When I run this method, it says: "SequelizeEagerLoadingError: User is associated to Action multiple times. To identify the correct association, you must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias of the association you want to include."

Just for the sake of it, I tried taking out this next part, but the error message said that the alias 'users_that_liked' wasn't correct:

```
      {
        model: User,
        attributes: ['id', 'name']
      }
```

I'm I defining the models wrong?